# learning shared weights

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, svm, model-averaging

I have a classification problem with 100 variables measured during 5 conditions, so 500 features. Some conditions are more informative than others, so I would like to have a learner that learns weights for every condition (5 weights, shared across features) and then use those weighted means (100) for a classification preferably by SVM. I have no idea how to do it, any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you assigned a neural-networks tag, I am going to assume that you want to solve this problem with a neural network.

I do not know how far your knowledge with respect to neural-networks reaches but you could simply feed the 500 feature values into a single softmax regression layer (for classification) with a modified gradient update.

The Softmax layer will have a (n_class x 500) weight matrix which will be optimised with respect to the loss function at each training step. Usually one would compute the gradient for each weight with respect to the loss function, and then update all of them accordingly, however this would not yield shared weights. The following altered gradient update would solve that.

Let's say that you structure your features to be f1c1, f1c2, f1c3, .. etc. Then rather then doing a conventional weight update for each weight with respect to its gradient you could update the weights by the average gradient of the same feature for different conditions. This means that that the weights of f1c1, f1c2, f1c3, f1c4, f1c5 would all be updated by (gf1c1 + gf1c2 + gf1c3 + gf1c4 + gf1c5)/5. This would ensure that the weights between the conditions of the same feature are shared, which you can extract at a later stage.

Sorry if the explanation is a little messy.

Comment: Thanks. I assigned NN tag, because I am willing to use them and I know it is possible to use them to produce this effect, however they are probably too complex and I believe I would be able to get better results with different methods. In my area, linear SVM is common practice (not enough samples, to do anything fancier). Your explanation makes total sense. Is there a way to make the net look for maximal margin separation hyperplane, similar to SVM?

Comment: There is not, however a similar effect can be obtained by adding a regulariser to the network during training. A common (and simple) choice is to use L2 decay, which penalises the squared sum of the weights. By doing so the network is less likely to overfit and will generalise better, which is a similar effect that is obtained by taking the maximal margin separation hyperplane, as opposed to a separation hyperplane with less margin

Comment: Now that i thought about it, your approach would not produce what i want. It will produce same weights per condition within feature, which is equivalent to just taking a mean of those conditions. But i think i can do MLP where one neuron represents one feature and have 5 weights from every condition and i will update those weights by a mean of deltas across features. Therefore i will learn weights for a weighted mean per feature, that are shared across features and also importance of individual features